# In bash, echoing a list removes '/'

Tags: bash

I found [this handy bash function](https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/48e2803c0ffa6dc2e0bd) for selecting and checking out a previous branch a while back.  It worked like a charm.  The key bits are:

```bash
  BRANCHES=(
    $(
      git reflog |
        egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" |
        awk '{ print $3 }' |        # extract 3rd column
        awk ' !x[$0]++' |           # Removes duplicates.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157
        egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | # remove hash results
        while read line; do         # verify existence
          ([[ $CHECK_EXISTENCE = '0' ]] || git rev-parse --verify "$line" &>/dev/null) && echo "$line"
        done |
        head -n "$NUM"
    )
  )

  if [[ $INTERACTIVE = '1' ]]; then
    PS3="Choose a branch: "

    select d in "${BRANCHES[@]}"; do
      test -n "$d" && break
      echo ">>> Invalid Selection"
    done

    git checkout "$d"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "${BRANCHES[@]}"
  fi
```

Our branch names are all of the form `bug/...` or `task/...`.

For some reason, today it started failing.  When I debugged it with `set -x`, I discovered that `echo ${BRANCHES[@]}`, which `select` appears to evaluate unquoted, is removing the `/`.

To simplify/verify the issue, I ran this:

```bash
foo=( "a/b" "c/d" )
echo $foo
# prints a b
echo ${foo[@]}
# prints a b c d
echo "${foo[@]}"
# prints a/b c/d
```

This issue is wreaking havoc all over my aliases/functions, as you might expect.

Strangely, while the function in the script prints:

```bash
1) master
task
2) 16658-...
task
3) 16525-...
Choose a branch:
```

Selecting from `foo` prints as expected:

```bash
select f in "${foo[@]}"; do
  echo $f
  break
done
# prompts:
# 1) a/b
# 2) c/d
```

so I may be wrong about the root cause, but I doubt it.  Selecting `1` in the prompt above echos `a b`.

In fact...

```bash
foo=a/b
echo $foo
# prints a b
echo "$foo"
# prints a/b

foo="a/b"
echo $foo
# prints a/b
```

If it matters, I'm using git-bash for Windows rather than unix bash, but I can't imagine that's the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `unset IFS`.

Comment: Oh, that fixed it!  Thank you!  Write it as an answer, and I'll mark it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@` in an unquoted expression

Comment: @roaima I wasn't.  `select` appeared to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you echo something unquoted, it is subjected to what is known as split+glob. This means that what you echo will be split on any characters in the variable `IFS` and then treated as a glob and, if it matches anything, that glob will be expanded. The part you care about here is the split. What you describe cannot happen with the default value of `IFS` (which is a space, a tab and a newline). If you are seeing this behavior, then you (or something in your shell session) has set `IFS` to something else, most likely a `/`. To illustrate:

```
$ foo=( "a/b" "c/d" )
$ echo ${foo[@]}
a/b c/d

## Now, change IFS
$ IFS='/'
$ echo ${foo[@]}
a b c d
## Of course, properly quoting fixes it
$ echo "${foo[@]}"
a/b c/d

## And so does un-setting IFS
$ unset IFS
$ echo ${foo[@]}
a/b c/d
```

This is just one of the reasons why you should always quote your variables. For more on that see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222).

Note that this explains why your examples are failing, not why your original script is failing. The original has everything properly quoted as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, I can't explain why the script was failing either, given the quoting.